# Adding additional store addresses

Tags: magento

Magento allows you to set five email addresses in the store admin:

- General Contact
- Sales Representative
- Customer Support
- Custom Email 1
- Custom Email 2

What do I do if I want more?

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a new module (or extends existing one in local code pool) and add a `system.xml` file.

Here's a quick example. Lets assume that you'd like to add 'Technical support' and 'HR department' email addresses. Your `system.xml` file would look like this:

```
<config>
    <sections>
        <trans_email>
            <groups>
                <ident_technical translate="label">
                    <label>Technical Support</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <email translate="label">
                            <label>Sender Email</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <backend_model>adminhtml/system_config_backend_email_address</backend_model>
                            <validate>validate-email</validate>
                            <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </email>
                        <name translate="label">
                            <label>Sender Name</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <backend_model>adminhtml/system_config_backend_email_sender</backend_model>
                            <validate>validate-emailSender</validate>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </name>
                    </fields>
                </ident_technical>
                <ident_hr translate="label">
                    <label>HR department</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <email translate="label">
                            <label>Sender Email</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <backend_model>adminhtml/system_config_backend_email_address</backend_model>
                            <validate>validate-email</validate>
                            <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </email>
                        <name translate="label">
                            <label>Sender Name</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <backend_model>adminhtml/system_config_backend_email_sender</backend_model>
                            <validate>validate-emailSender</validate>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </name>
                    </fields>
                </ident_hr>
            </groups>
        </trans_email>
    </sections>
</config>
```

In your code you can get e.g. Technical support data by

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_technical/email');
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a blog on this. Maybe this is useful

http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-sending-custom-emails

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new module and create an adminhtml folder in the etc folder. Here, create a system.xml and add the following code:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="trans_email" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="90" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <tab>general</tab>
            <group id="ident_custom3" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="6" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Custom Email 3</label>
                <field id="email" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
                    <label>Sender Email</label>
                    <validate>validate-email</validate>
                    <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Email\Address</backend_model>
                </field>
                <field id="name" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
                    <label>Sender Name</label>
                    <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Email\Sender</backend_model>
                    <validate>validate-emailSender</validate>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

This will add a Custom Email 3 section at Stores ->Configurations ->General ->Store Email Addresses.